# Is と a non-logical particle?

Tags: grammar, particles

Consider

> もしたくさんの遺産が**あったとしたらど**のように使うのですか？
>
> Say if it so happened that you had a lot of inheritance, how would you use it?

I was under the impression that と is a logical particle, meaning it is a particle placed after nouns to indicate grammatical relationships with other nouns.  But here, と is being placed after a clause/non-noun (あった).

**Question:** Is there an implicit の[こと] being dropped before the と here? Or is と not considered a logical particle?

Comment: You've never come across the conditional と or the quotative と, neither of which have to come after a noun? There is nothing missing. Xとしたら simply means "if we suppose that X".

Comment: @user3856370: I have, but I just thought that was a different と. If it's not, that's an interesting point :)

Comment: To be honest I'm not sure which と this one is, but I'm pretty sure it's not the conjunctive one that you seem to be referencing.  I just treat it as a separate particle. I guess it would be interesting to know if it is actually the quote particle in disguise.

Comment: I think としたら is generally considered to be its own separate particle by most people, and not really broken down any further.  However, if you were to break it down, I believe this is really just a case of the quotative と, essentially taking the previous phrase and labelling it as the referent for the following したら (conditional/hypothetical form of する). ("this thing I just said (と), if it were to happen (したら)")

Comment: Hi George, are you referring to the logical vs non-logical particles discussed here? https://learnjapaneseonline.info/2017/05/24/japanese-particles-wa-vs-ga/

Comment: @rebuuilt Yes, that's the sense I'm using the word.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure what you mean by "(non-)logical particle", but this と is essentially a quotative-と, which naturally takes a clause that ends with a verb (見た**と**思います), an adjective (赤い**と**思います) or a copula (学生だ**と**思います). This する is a verb meaning "to let/assume" (see the 5th definition [on jisho](https://jisho.org/word/%E7%82%BA%E3%82%8B)), and `sentence + とする` is a set phrase meaning "assume that ～". There is no fundamental grammatical difference between 遺産があったと思う and 遺産があったとする.

と can directly take a noun, too, in which case it's a different type of particle that typically means "with ～" (as in 彼と働く "to work with him") or "and" (as in リンゴとバナナ "apples and bananas"). Let's not mix them.